# Use Joi library with react-native typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, joi

I am trying to use Joi (https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.1) library with react-native for json format data validation.

It gives the error `ReferenceError: Property 'TextEncoder' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes` and says defined Joi schemas are undefined.

Could anyone please help on this to resolve ?